# How to get current cell value in GridView binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

Having spent the last few hours with this rather simple problem, I haven't yet found a way to do it. I'm using a `GridView` to display some data and need to perform some customization of the cell values using a converter. Here is the relevant XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeDataTable}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=XXX, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

What do I need to write in place of XXX above?

N.B. I cannot put constant column name here because this DataTemplate is to be used by all columns of GridView. I need a way to refer to **current cell value** just like how GridView's default template works when using `DisplayMemberBinding`.

I found a relevant post [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e99e37ca-ee4d-429f-afbd-29a6b874d270/gridviewcolumn-displaymemberbinding-and-celltemplate-precedence?forum=wpf), but that also doesn't have any working answer.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @ShloimeRosenblum: A whole lot. Including trying to write the cell template I posted above and going as far as writing my own template selector. No obvious way to get current cell value.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use DisplayMemberBinding to create the GridViewColumns and then to define your TextBlock's style as a resource of your ListView and to use a converter there.

Given a scenario where I have a list of persons and I want to color all the cells based on the person's age:

**Data item:**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(int age, string name)
    {
        Age = age;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

**Creating the columns in XAML:**

```
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}"  />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

**The converter which changes cell background based on the age:**

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((int) value < 20)
        {
            return Brushes.LightBlue;
        }

        return Brushes.LightGreen;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Using the converter:**

```
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Binding Path="Age">
                            <Binding.Converter>
                                <local:MyConverter/>
                            </Binding.Converter>
                        </Binding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
```

**Result:**

[image: Converter and GridViewColumn]

**Full XAML:**

```
    <ListView x:Name="MyItems" Loaded="MyItems_OnLoaded">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Binding Path="Age">
                            <Binding.Converter>
                                <local:MyConverter/>
                            </Binding.Converter>
                        </Binding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}"  />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```